How to properly convert mp4 to HEVC Dash using FFmpeg?
I want to convert a mp4 video to HEVC dash, but after the conversion it's not playable on any browser, it only plays on VLC. I tested on Chrome latest version, with dash.js, plyr.io and videojs.
I checked the demo player at https://reference.dashif.org/dash.js/nightly/samples/dash-if-reference-player/index.html and the mpd file they use to play HEVC, and they all include a "version" for the mpd codecs like: codecs="hev1.2.6.L186.0", while my mpd file only have codecs="hev1" if I change it to codecs="hev1.2.6.L186.0" it will work and play the video on the browser, but it doesn't seem to be right to change that manually. FFmpeg should do this automatically.
Basic example:
h264:
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -c:v libx264 -b:v 1000k -c:a aac -b:a 128k -f dash -seg_duration 10 -min_seg_duration 10 "dash-test/playlist.mpd"

It's playable.
h265 hevc:
ffmpeg -i video.mkv -pix_fmt yuv420p -tag:v hvc1 -c:v libx265 -b:v 1000k -c:a aac -b:a 128k -f dash -seg_duration 10 -min_seg_duration 10 "dash-test/playlist.mpd"

Generate this mpd bellow:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MPD xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="urn:mpeg:dash:schema:mpd:2011"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    xsi:schemaLocation="urn:mpeg:DASH:schema:MPD:2011 http://standards.iso.org/ittf/PubliclyAvailableStandards/MPEG-DASH_schema_files/DASH-MPD.xsd"
    profiles="urn:mpeg:dash:profile:isoff-live:2011"
    type="static"
    mediaPresentationDuration="PT2M32.8S"
    maxSegmentDuration="PT10.0S"
    minBufferTime="PT20.8S">
    <ProgramInformation>
    </ProgramInformation>
    <ServiceDescription id="0">
    </ServiceDescription>
    <Period id="0" start="PT0.0S">
        <AdaptationSet id="0" contentType="video" startWithSAP="1" segmentAlignment="true" bitstreamSwitching="true" frameRate="24000/1001" maxWidth="1920" maxHeight="1080" par="16:9" lang="und">
            <Representation id="0" mimeType="video/mp4" codecs="hvc1" bandwidth="1000000" width="1920" height="1080" sar="1:1">
                <SegmentTemplate timescale="24000" initialization="init-stream$RepresentationID$.m4s" media="chunk-stream$RepresentationID$-$Number%05d$.m4s" startNumber="1">
                    <SegmentTimeline>
                        <S t="0" d="272272" />
                        <S d="254254" />
                        <S d="242242" />
                        <S d="250250" />
                        <S d="283283" />
                        <S d="251251" />
                        <S d="270270" />
                        <S d="307307" />
                        <S d="274274" />
                        <S d="273273" />
                        <S d="240240" />
                        <S d="346346" />
                        <S d="247247" />
                        <S d="156156" />
                    </SegmentTimeline>
                </SegmentTemplate>
            </Representation>
        </AdaptationSet>
        <AdaptationSet id="1" contentType="audio" startWithSAP="1" segmentAlignment="true" bitstreamSwitching="true" lang="eng">
            <Representation id="1" mimeType="audio/mp4" codecs="mp4a.40.2" bandwidth="128000" audioSamplingRate="44100">
                <AudioChannelConfiguration schemeIdUri="urn:mpeg:dash:23003:3:audio_channel_configuration:2011" value="2" />
                <SegmentTemplate timescale="44100" initialization="init-stream$RepresentationID$.m4s" media="chunk-stream$RepresentationID$-$Number%05d$.m4s" startNumber="1">
                    <SegmentTimeline>
                        <S t="0" d="440320" />
                        <S d="441344" r="13" />
                        <S d="124928" />
                    </SegmentTimeline>
                </SegmentTemplate>
            </Representation>
        </AdaptationSet>
    </Period>
</MPD>

And it's only playable if I manually change the codecs from codecs="hvc1" to codecs="hev1.2.6.L186.0". Why is this happening and how to fix it?

https://superuser.com/a/1851117/788170

@JayCravens The answer you linked is for h264.

Yeah.  Change one character, it's 265.

@JayCravens I did this, and the video output was the same I described in my question, not playable, unles I change the value of the codecs inside the .mpd. Where does the value from codecs come from? How to set it in the ffmpeg command? This is the problem.

Hmm.  Weird.  Try -level 5.1 (for best DASH compatibility) and -allow_extradata 1 could help with the .mpd by adding info. Also, shouldn't it be -tag:v hev1?

If you use dash.js to watch hevc in chrome, you can add following code to DashManifestModel.js -> getCodec() before return codec
if (codec === 'video/mp4;codecs="hev1"'|| codec === 'video/mp4;codecs="hvc1"') {
        codec = 'video/mp4;codecs="hvc1.2.4.L90.B0"';
    }

In dash.js 4.7.4 it works for me with graphic acceleration
P.S
In order for ffmpeg to set the correct hevc codec-tag, you need to add some handling code for codec_str here and build ffmpeg.
If you will find another way how to do it, or maybe write a method for it, tag me pls.

Your answer is interesting. But to get a Hevc Dash stream, things seem too complex, so I'll stick with HLS. I was able to convert an h.264 video to Hevc HLS and it is playable on the web.
